# How to config Tomcat for case insensitive URL?

Tags: url, tomcat, case-insensitive

I need URL to be CASE-INSENSITIVE in Tomcat.
I mean when I write in browser's address bar for example 'http://localhost/index.htm'
is not equals 'http://localhost/INDEX.htm' and then i get error because this page(INDEX.htm) there isn't.
how i can config Tomcat6 for case insensitive URL?
Thank you

Comment: You know that it breaks the web when you do this kind of thing, right?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No it doesn't. In the real world, people do not use case sensitive URLs. Nor should they.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Yes, it does. In the real world, the scheme-dependent part of any URL is case-sensitive. Here's an example you may find instructive. http://www.homedepot.com/s/hammer?NCNI-5 finds hammers on Home Depot's web site, while http://www.homedepot.com/S/hammer?NCNI-5 gives you a `404 Not Found` response.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz And that is a bad implementation. Both of those should give you the same result. It is horrible usability that it doesn't, because real people (the "real world" I am talking about) don't want to have to worry about the case of a URL they are entering, nor should they have to. And in any good website, it shouldn't matter. Both http://smile.amazon.com/Dont-Make-Think-Revisited-Usability/dp/0321965515/ and http://smile.amazon.com/dont-make-think-revisited-usability/dp/0321965515/ give you the same product page, which is how it should be.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz It doesn't matter that a particular website does things wrong, which Home Depot does (side note, when I built Home Depot's websites several revisions ago, the URLs were NOT case sensitive), it matters what the users expect, and users expect a URL to work regardless of the case of the characters in the URL.

Comment: Users aren't expected to enter URLs by hand, other than perhaps the hostname. Case-insensitive URLs (and filesystems!) are a great way to introduce security vulnerabilities of various kinds. The [W3C] (http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1) disagrees with you. The [cookie spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.4) disagrees with you. But I think this comes down to background: those who have traditionally worked in UNIX-style environments expect everything to be case-sensitive and those who have worked in Windows-based environments expect case-insensitive. YMMV.

Comment: Also, [IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811021/how-to-enable-case-sensitivity-under-iis-express) disagrees.

Answer (score 4):

It is *possible* in Tomcat 6 and earlier, but not **recommended**. 
Refer this [Link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) from apache documentation. Search for `caseSensitive`. By default it is `true`

Comment: Where i should set caseSensitive=false ? in web.xml and context.xml and .. Does not give me caseSensitive Attribute.

Comment: Remember, it is available in Tomcat 6 and below. Set in context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on whether you use Tomcat or Apache for HTML rendering.  You can configure Apache 2.4 to render HTML and delegate JSP to Tomcat.  In this scenario, you can configure Apache to be case insensitive.  See this [link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814419/how-do-i-make-urls-case-insensitive-in-linux-server)

Usually jsp pages are referenced by links, so the developer controls the case of the URL.