# Website not running when given in lowercase

Tags: asp.net

I am having a website with the url.
    [http://192.168.13.127/ReportWebsite/Login.aspx] ,which works fine. 
if i give the url in smaller case,the page is refreshing and not loading

[http://192.168.13.127/reportwebsite/Login.aspx] ,what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What IIS version? OS of the server?

Comment: its windows 7 OS. IIS version is 7.5

Comment: See [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8981186/447356) good chance you have URL Rewrite module in place thus those two URL's mean two different pages.

Answer (score 0):

URL's are very specific, and depending on the server case sensitive. it considers Hi.asp and hi.asp different pages